# AngularJS - Finding width of changing DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I feel like most of my Angular questions I ask are me missing something incredibly dumb, so let's hope this is too.

I'm building a directive to control scrolling of a wide list of thumbnails.  In jQuery, I had this working perfectly, but the jQuery wasn't comfortable with grabbing a dynamically loaded list from Angular, so I'm rewriting my code.  Basically, I've got a gallery that exists in an ng-repeat:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul id="gallery_img">
        <li class="thumb" ng-repeat="image in thumbnails">
            <img ng-src="{{image.thumbnail}}" alt="{{image.description}}" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and when I click on some further-down buttons,

```
<slider class="mover" style="left:0;">&laquo;</slider>
<slider class="mover" style="right:0;">&raquo;</slider>
```

the list is supposed to animate/slide backwards and forwards the width of the image in my "0" position.  Basically, it grabs the width, then adds that width to my UL left position.  Super simple, right?

Here's the directive I've got controlling this movement at the moment:

```
app.directive('slider', function() { //to reuse, replace "#gallery_img" with whatever you want
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var toMove = angular.element('#gallery_img');
            var imageWidth;
            var imageNumber = 1;
            element.bind('mousedown', function(){
                toMove.css({left: '-=200'});
                console.log(toMove.children([imageNumber]).width());
                console.log(imageNumber);
                imageNumber +=1;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I added in some console.log details, so that I could see what widths I'm getting.  My imageNumber is definitely changing; each time I click next or previous, the number goes up one.  The width I'm getting, though, is only for the first image in each set; I've got several galleries, but no matter how many times I click "next," gallery one will only ever give me "566," gallery two only "433", gallery three "521."  Each image is of an entirely different size, so... why is it only giving me the width of the first image?

e: Here's a plnkr of what I'm talking about:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nLG4OKsNGvYTgEMg9UOv

Comment: It would be useful to see this as a Plunkr or Fiddle

Comment: can you create a plunker with your sample slider? Also, there's already a bunch of out-of-the-box angular gallery sliders that exist if you want to save yourself some time.

Comment: Added plunkr to initial post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code:

```
toMove.children([imageNumber]).width()
```

You are passing `imageNumber` to the `children` function. The `children` function accepts an optional selector, not an indexer. In your case this will probably return a jQuery object containing all the `li` and the call to `width()` will return the width of the first.

Instead pass the indexer to what the `children` function returns and go from there (dividing for clarity):

```
var children = toMove.children()
var width = $(children[imageNumber]).width();
console.log(width);
```

Or:

```
var width = toMove.children().eq(imageNumber).width();
console.log(width);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize I could use .eq in an AngularJS selector; you've made this slider possible.

Comment: You're welcome :) As long as you load jQuery before Angular, `angular.element` is actually an alias for the jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

Check this to help you debug:

```
console.log(toMove.children().length); // how many children are seen?
```

then

```
angular.forEach(toMove.children(), function(element, index){
    console.log(index, angular.element(element).width());
});
```